# How to fill a prompt asking for input with a secret in Github Actions?

Tags: bash, github, github-actions

Doing the following step inside a job:

```
name: Add Secret Key
  run: ssh-add - <<< "${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}"
```

I get prompted to fill in the passphrase.

How do I use another secret, such as `"${{ secrets.PASSPHRASE }}"` to fill the prompt?

Currently I get this error:
[image]

Because "*Enter passphrase for (stdin):*" step is skipped

Answer (score 1):

You should not be prompted for a passphrase unless the private key was originally created with a passphrase.

For example, consider an action like [`actions/webfactory-ssh-agent`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/webfactory-ssh-agent), which comes from the study done in "[Using a SSH deploy key in GitHub Actions to access private repositories](https://www.webfactory.de/blog/use-ssh-key-for-private-repositories-in-github-actions)" done by [Matthias Pigulla](https://twitter.com/mpdude_de)

> GitHub Actions only have access to the repository they run for. So, in order to access additional private repositories, create an SSH key with sufficient access privileges.
> Then, use this action to make the key available with ssh-agent on the Action worker node. Once this has been set up, git clone commands using ssh URLs will just work.

```yaml
# .github/workflows/my-workflow.yml
jobs:
    my_job:
        ...
        steps:
            - actions/checkout@v1
            # Make sure the @v0.4.1 matches the current version of the
            # action 
            - uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.4.1
              with:
                  ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
            - ... other steps
```

Its [README](https://github.com/webfactory/ssh-agent/blob/ee29fafb6aa450493bac9136b346e51ea60a8b5e/README.md) does include:

> ### Creating SSH keys
>
> In order to create a new SSH key, run `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -a 100 -f path/to/keyfile`, as suggested in this blog post.
> If you need to work with some older server software and need RSA keys, try `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -o -f path/to/keyfile` instead.
>
> Both commands will prompt you for a key passphrase and save the key in `path/to/keyfile`.
> In general, having a passphrase is a good thing, since it will keep the key encrypted on your disk.
>
> **When using the key with this action, however, you need to make sure you don't specify a passphrase: The key must be usable without reading the passphrase from input. Since the key itself is stored using GitHub's "Secret" feature, it should be fairly safe anyway.**